# Unable to define a method in typescript file in the simple way

Tags: typescript, methods

I'm trying to define a method in the simple way:

```
   method(arg: string): any {
      // code
   }
```

But it is not working.

If I define it like this then it works:

```
   const method = ((arg: string) => {
      // code
   });
```

Why can't I define the method in the simple way?

Answer (score 2):

Outside of a class, that syntax isn't valid. If you want to declare a named function, some other options are:

```
function method(arg: string) : any {
}

const method = function(arg: string) : any {
};
```